# Why my url's are encoded in nginx.conf?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, centos

Basically I have this `nginx.conf` file where I receive some parameters from my `index.html` page form. One of these parameters is called `$url` and I use it to do a:

```
proxy_pass $url;
```

The thing is that the operation fails because the `$url` seem to be encoded and in my error.log file I see something like this:

```
[error] 18849#18849: *195088 invalid URL prefix in "http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com"
```

However, if I hardcode the operation like this:

```
proxy_pass http://example.com;
```

or like this:

```
set $url_backup http://example.com
proxy_pass $url_backup;
```

it works without any problem.

How can I fix the URL issue ? Thanks

Comment: Hello, are you using GET or POST in your `index.html` form? This shows clearly that your form is posting your values encoded, which is normal.

Comment: I use GET because I heared that nginx does not know about POST. Basically my url looks like this: http://www.my-url.com?myURL=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com and I want to use the myUrl param.

Comment: How did you get `$url` variable?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, as you are using GET parameters for your $url syntax, encoding of strings is compulsory for HTTP's URLs.
That's why every special char is escaped from your form to your URL.

But you can get your things done by a LUA scripot with the [nginx-lua-module](https://github.com/chaoslawful/lua-nginx-module)'s [ngx-escape-uri](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxescape_uri) by decoding your URL:

```
newstr = ngx.unescape_uri($url)
```

(depending on how you got your URL)

Sources: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20282054/how-to-urldecode-a-request-uri-string-in-lua

Comment: I am intrested to do it natively without adding new modules to nginx.